# #Appcelerator Ti.Paint Android not saving image

Tags: android, appcelerator

I know the paint module is very simple, and I have been using versions of it for years. Recently, (version 2.0.3), the pantView.toImage().media has stopped working. I actually us it to save a snapshot of the display so it is win.toImage().media. It gives me a 0 kb file. It detects a file, but it is empty. Any ideas how I can remedy the situation?

Appcelerator SDK 5.2.0 GA

Ti.Paint 2.0.3

Android OS target 6.0.x

Windows 8.1

```
    var sigImg = win.toImage().media; 
var filename = (Ti.App.currentWorkOrderId + "_signature.png");
    var img = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,filename);
if(img.exists){
    img.deleteFile();
}
img.write(sigImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure with Android 6 you have the storage permission enabled on the phone? Could it be it's not saving because it's not allowed? Remember with Android 6 you now must ask for permissions differently than previous Android versions...

Ray

Comment: The read/write privs are set (I checked again just to be sure). Still no glory. Thanks, though.

Comment: Also, I loaded an earlier version of the app (from Titanium 4.1 or so) on my Android 6.x device and it saved the image without issue. I believe it is a problem with the toImage().media method. I tried casting the sigImg to a blob using sigImg.toBlob(); and received the error "Cannot call method toBlob of undefined.

Comment: Keeping the running commentary going... I tried another approach. I created a new field in a table in the SQLite DB I use in the app and save the image as a string using Ti.Utils.base64encode(sigImg).toString(). I tested by creating a viewer and pulling it out of the db and converting back to blob. The image appears properly. So, the method toImage() is working. It just won't save the png in app_appdata directory. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just checked an app where I use Ti.Paint and works on Android 6. Using Paint 2.03. This code works for me: ```var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, 'signature.png');  ```
  ```var result = f.write(paint.toImage());  ```
  ```Ti.API.info('Saved signature returned ' +result);  ```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Here is my code for saving the images, it works very well. You can inspire you.. I hope you can solve your problem !

```
function path(imageName) {
return Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,imageName+".png");} 


function loadImage(imageName) {
try {
     var imageFile = path(imageName);

     if(imageFile.nativePath) {
        canvas.image = imageFile.nativePath;
        console.log("LOAD !");
     }
}
catch(err) {
    console.log("ERREUR : ",err);
}}



function saveImage(imageName) {
try {
    var imageFile = path(imageName);

    imageFile.write(canvas.toImage());
    console.log("SAVE !");
  }
catch(err) {
      console.log("ERREUR : ",err);
  }}
```